# Validate dynamically created Check box and Radio buttons

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-validation

I have an application in which dynamically check boxes and radio buttons get generated based on the data sent from the server. The number of check box/radio button displayed can increase up to 20 (in a single group).

My question is, what is the best method to validate a group of check box, radio button which are generated dynamically and also they are part of the same form element.

Below is the code which I am using
The data is of similar to the format below

```
 $scope.values = [
  { Type: 'CheckBox', 
    IsRequired: true,
    Id:1,
    Options: [
      {
        Id: 11,
        Text: 'Test 1',
      },
      {
        Id: 12,
        Text: 'Test 2',
      },
      {
        Id: 13,
        Text: 'Test 3',
      },
      {
        Id: 14,
        Text: 'Test 4',
      }
      ]
  },
  { Type: 'Radio',
     IsRequired: 'true',
     Id: 2,
     Options: [
       {
         Id: 21,
         Text: 'Radio 1',
       },
       {
         Id: 22,
         Text: 'Radio 2',
       },
       {
         Id: 23,
         Text: 'Radio 3',
       },
       {
         Id: 24,
         Text: 'Radio 4',
       },
      ]
  },
];
```

And for building the view I am using the below code for generating check boxes

```
<div ng-class="{ 'has-errors' : testForm.cb_{{q.Id}}.$invalid && {{q.IsRequired}} == true, 'no-errors' :
          testForm.cb_{{q.Id}}.$valid && {{q.IsRequired}} == true}">
     <ion-checkbox class="item" ng-repeat="opt in q.Options"
              name="cb_{{q.Id}}"
              ng-required="q.IsRequired"
              ng-model="options">
            {{opt.Text}}
     </ion-checkbox>
</div>
```

Below code for radio button

```
<div ng-class="{ 'has-errors' : testForm.rb_{{q.Id}}.$invalid
       && {{q.IsRequired}} == true, 'no-errors' : testForm.rb_{{q.Id}}.$valid
       && {{q.IsRequired}} == true}">
    <ion-radio ng-repeat="opt in q.Options"
         ng-model="choice" 
           name="rb_{{q.Id}}"
           ng-value="opt.Id"
           ng-required="true">{{opt.Text}}
    </ion-radio>
 </div>
```

Comment: All your radio buttons will need the same name to act as a group, the code for your check boxes seems fine unless you only need one or more of the check boxes to be selected

Comment: Correct that part I am aware off. My Radio buttons has same name. But the problem I am facing is an efficient way to validate both checkbox and radio buttons.

Comment: Okay, first of all you can remove the ` && {{q.IsRequired}} == true` from the ng-class as if you set required on the element and it's not selected it will be $invalid or $valid. As for the grouped check boxes you'll need to write a function for your ng-required to check if any of the check boxes are selected then set required to false. P.S, what does your model for the check boxes look like?

Comment: For check box I have written a method, which tells if it is required and coming to the model for check box it is a simple boolean variable.